# Buscar elemento en Data.Map

Tags: lista, map, haskell, data, modulos

Necesito retornar un elemento de un `Data.Map` en Haskell pero no entiendo como realizar esto. El tipo que tengo es:

```
type MapaH = Data.Map.Map String [Int]
```

Y se puede llenar como

```
rellenar :: MapaH
rellenar = Data.Map.fromList [ ("hola",[1,2,3]), 
                            ("prepa",[4,5,6]),
                            ("como",[7,8,9])]
```

Necesito saber como buscar la lista de numeros dependiendo del String que inserte, he intentado varias opciones para poder recorrer `MapaH` pero todo tiene errores. La función debería ser:

```
verHyo :: MapaH -> [Int]
```

Pero la única forma en la que entiendo como realizarlo es:

```
ver:: MapaH -> Maybe [Int]
ver s = Mp.lookup s rellenar
```

Necesito eliminar el Just al retornarlo en consola:

```
*Main> verHyo "hola"
Just [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

La función `(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a` se utiliza para acceder al elemento n-ésimo de una lista. El paquete [Data.Map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Map.html) define sus propias funciones para acceder a los elementos de un `Map`:

- `(!) :: Ord k => Map k a -> k -> a`
- `lookup :: Ord k => k -> Map k a -> Maybe a`

Ten en cuenta que `(!)` lanza un error si la clave no existe, por lo que si la clave puede fallar deberías utilizar `lookup` en su lugar.

```hs
Prelude Data.Map> Data.Map.lookup "hola" rellenar
Just [1,2,3]
Prelude Data.Map> Data.Map.lookup "foo" rellenar
Nothing
```

```hs
Prelude Data.Map> rellenar ! "hola"
[1,2,3]
Prelude Data.Map> rellenar ! "foo"
*** Exception: Map.!: given key is not an element in the map
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries\\containers\\containers\\src\\Data\\Map\\Internal.hs:627:17 in containers-0.6.2.1:Data.Map.Internal
```

Comment: Existe forma de eliminar ese Just que me retorna?

Comment: Puedes utilizar un ajuste de patrones para extraer el valor de `Maybe` o utilizar las funciones `fromJust` (insegura) o `fromMaybe` (con un valor por defecto para `Nothing`) del módulo `Data.Maybe`. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html